# google map overlays custom action bar menu

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

When I open the map activity this screen is shown:

http://tinypic.com/r/29frcn/5

After clicking on the action bar, this is the menu that should show:

http://tinypic.com/r/tziic/5

But instead of that, just the first option of the menu is shown. I can not attach screenshot because it gives the second image too (I know it's so weird).

So, the problem is that the menu is not displayed, but the options are there. In front of the screen there is the action bar, the first option, and the rest is the map. But if I clicked in the middle of the map, it detects it over the option and it goes to the correct page.

What is the problem of not showing the options but working "properly"?

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the width of the menu to be fixed instead of wrap content and if that works then probably u are using some scroll view or inherited class of its, so possibly customise it or else keeping width to be fixed should work.

Comment: I have used wrap_content, match_parent and a fixed width in dip units, and none of them are working. The most weird thing is that when I take a screenshot with the phone, the screenshot image is what it should be!!!

Comment: Can you add a small code snippet as i faced the same problem and it was resolved using the fixed width. Remove wrap content whereever you have used it and then try, hopefully that should work.

Comment: I give more information. For the first time I open the page, the map loads but the action bar is not displayed as I said before. But if I move to another page and then I go back, then the menu is displayed as it should. any idea?